# Hibernate - avoid redundent queries when settting a property for an object

Tags: java, hibernate, set, query-optimization

I have two entities named Product and Customer. There is a ManyToOne Relationship between them, meaning a customer can have many products while a product can only belong to one customer. So in my product class I have:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "account_holder", nullable = false)
public Customer getCustomer(){
    return customer;
}
```

and in my customer class I have:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
public Set<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
}
```

When setting the customer for a particular product (when updating the product), I load the customer by the customer id like below:

```
productbean.setCustomer(CustomerManager.getCustomer(this.productCustomer));
ProductManager.saveOrUpdate(productbean);
```

Now my problem is, setting the customer for this product causes many unnecessary queries to run. This happens only when I try to set the customer. I was wondering if there is any way to avoid this. Appreciate any help on this.

Here is my getCustomer method:

```
public Customer getCustomer(long id)
{
    return (Customer) session.load(Customer.class, id);
}
```

and my Product Class:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7982984161342095617L;

private int id;
private long accNumber;
private String name;
private double accLimit;
private Status status;
private Customer customer;

/**
 * @return the id
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @return the accNumber
 */
@Column(name="account_num")
public long getAccNumber() {
    return accNumber;
}

/**
 * @return the productName
 */
@Column(name="product_name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @return the accLimit
 */
@Column(name="account_limit")
public double getAccLimit() {
    return accLimit;
}

/**
 * @return the status
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="status")
public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
}

/**
 * @return the customer
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "account_holder", nullable = false)
public Customer getCustomer(){
    return customer;
}

/**
 * @param id the id to set
 */
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @param accNumber the accNumber to set
 */
public void setAccNumber(long accNumber) {
    this.accNumber = accNumber;
}

/**
 * @param productName the productName to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @param accLimit the accLimit to set
 */
public void setAccLimit(double accLimit) {
    this.accLimit = accLimit;
}

/**
 * @param status the status to set
 */
public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
}

/**
 * @param customer the customer to set
 */
public void setCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    this.customer = customer;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="product_status")
public static class Status implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7844926322256321866L;
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

}
```

and Customer Class:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1451775337978306021L;
private long id;
private Salutation salutation; 
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String prfdName;
private String nic;
private String passport;
private String mobileNum;
private String alterNum;
private String email;
private String addressLine1;
private String addressLine2;
private String addressLine3;
private String town;
private String district;
private long postalCode;
private Language prfdLanguage;
private Date joinDate;
private Date dob;
private String branch;
private String relManager;
private Status status;
private User creator;
private Date creationDate;
private Set<Interaction> interactions = new HashSet<Interaction>(0);
private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>(0);



@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="salutation")
public Salutation getSalutation() {
    return salutation;
}

@Column(name="first_name")
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

@Column(name="last_name")
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

@Column(name="prfd_name")
public String getPrfdName() {
    return prfdName;
}

@Column(name="nic")
public String getNic() {
    return nic;
}

@Column(name="passport")
public String getPassport() {
    return passport;
}

@Column(name="mobile_num")
public String getMobileNum() {
    return mobileNum;
}

@Column(name="alter_num")
public String getAlterNum() {
    return alterNum;
}

@Column(name="email")
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

@Column(name="address_1")
public String getAddressLine1() {
    return addressLine1;
}

@Column(name="address_2")
public String getAddressLine2() {
    return addressLine2;
}

@Column(name="address_3")
public String getAddressLine3() {
    return addressLine3;
}

@Column(name="town")
public String getTown() {
    return town;
}

@Column(name="district")
public String getDistrict() {
    return district;
}

@Column(name="postal_code")
public long getPostalCode() {
    return postalCode;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="prfd_language")
public Language getPrfdLanguage() {
    return prfdLanguage;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="join_date")
public Date getJoinDate() {
    return joinDate;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="dob")
public Date getDob() {
    return dob;
}

@Column(name="branch")
public String getBranch() {
    return branch;
}

@Column(name="rel_manager")
public String getRelManager() {
    return relManager;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="status")
public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="created_by")
public User getCreator() {
    return creator;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="creation_date")
public Date getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
public Set<Interaction> getInteractions() {
    return interactions;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
public Set<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
}



public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setSalutation(Salutation salutation) {
    this.salutation = salutation;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public void setPrfdName(String prfdName) {
    this.prfdName = prfdName;
}

public void setNic(String nic) {
    this.nic = nic;
}

public void setPassport(String passport) {
    this.passport = passport;
}

public void setMobileNum(String mobileNum) {
    this.mobileNum = mobileNum;
}

public void setAlterNum(String alterNum) {
    this.alterNum = alterNum;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
    this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
}

public void setAddressLine2(String addressLine2) {
    this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
}

public void setAddressLine3(String addressLine3) {
    this.addressLine3 = addressLine3;
}

public void setTown(String town) {
    this.town = town;
}

public void setDistrict(String district) {
    this.district = district;
}

public void setPostalCode(long postalCode) {
    this.postalCode = postalCode;
}

public void setPrfdLanguage(Language prfdLanguage) {
    this.prfdLanguage = prfdLanguage;
}

public void setJoinDate(Date joinDate) {
    this.joinDate = joinDate;
}

public void setDob(Date dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}

public void setBranch(String branch) {
    this.branch = branch;
}

public void setRelManager(String relManager) {
    this.relManager = relManager;
}

public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public void setCreator(User creator) {
    this.creator = creator;
}

public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}

public void setInteractions(Set<Interaction> interactions) {
    this.interactions = interactions;
}

public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
    this.products = products;
}



@Entity
@Table(name="customer_status")
public static class Status implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2149364276152128818L;
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name="customer_salutation")
public static class Salutation implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4963516558091334778L;
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name="customer_language")
public static class Language implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5569029827581841931L;
    private int id;
    private String name;



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

}
```

and here are my hibernate log showing all the queries running:

```
Hibernate: select customer0_.id as id3_0_, customer0_.created_by as created23_3_0_, customer0_.status as status3_0_, customer0_.creation_date as creation2_3_0_, customer0_.first_name as first3_3_0_, customer0_.last_name as last4_3_0_, customer0_.salutation as salutation3_0_, customer0_.prfd_name as prfd5_3_0_, customer0_.nic as nic3_0_, customer0_.passport as passport3_0_, customer0_.mobile_num as mobile8_3_0_, customer0_.alter_num as alter9_3_0_, customer0_.email as email3_0_, customer0_.address_1 as address11_3_0_, customer0_.address_2 as address12_3_0_, customer0_.address_3 as address13_3_0_, customer0_.town as town3_0_, customer0_.district as district3_0_, customer0_.postal_code as postal16_3_0_, customer0_.prfd_language as prfd22_3_0_, customer0_.join_date as join17_3_0_, customer0_.dob as dob3_0_, customer0_.branch as branch3_0_, customer0_.rel_manager as rel20_3_0_ from customer customer0_ where customer0_.id=?
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id0_0_, user0_.username as username0_0_, user0_.role as role0_0_, user0_.status as status0_0_, user0_.password as password0_0_, user0_.firstname as firstname0_0_, user0_.lastname as lastname0_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?
Hibernate: select user_role0_.id as id2_0_, user_role0_.name as name2_0_ from user_roles user_role0_ where user_role0_.id=?
Hibernate: select user_statu0_.id as id1_0_, user_statu0_.name as name1_0_ from user_status user_statu0_ where user_statu0_.id=?
Hibernate: select interactio0_.customer_id as customer10_1_, interactio0_.id as id1_, interactio0_.id as id7_0_, interactio0_.interaction_type as interac11_7_0_, interactio0_.interaction_time as interact2_7_0_, interactio0_.interaction_date as interact3_7_0_, interactio0_.created_by as created13_7_0_, interactio0_.status as status7_0_, interactio0_.interaction_id as interact4_7_0_, interactio0_.channel_type as channel7_7_0_, interactio0_.interaction_categ1 as interac12_7_0_, interactio0_.interaction_categ2 as interact6_7_0_, interactio0_.escalated_to as escalated8_7_0_, interactio0_.notes as notes7_0_, interactio0_.customer_id as customer10_7_0_ from interaction interactio0_ where interactio0_.customer_id=?
Hibernate: select interactio0_.id as id10_0_, interactio0_.name as name10_0_, interactio0_.parent as parent10_0_ from interaction_categ1 interactio0_ where interactio0_.id=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select interactio0_.id as id8_0_, interactio0_.name as name8_0_ from interaction_type interactio0_ where interactio0_.id=?
Hibernate: select categs1x0_.parent as parent1_, categs1x0_.id as id1_, categs1x0_.id as id10_0_, categs1x0_.name as name10_0_, categs1x0_.parent as parent10_0_ from interaction_categ1 categs1x0_ where categs1x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select interactio0_.id as id9_0_, interactio0_.name as name9_0_ from interaction_channel_type interactio0_ where interactio0_.id=?
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id0_0_, user0_.username as username0_0_, user0_.role as role0_0_, user0_.status as status0_0_, user0_.password as password0_0_, user0_.firstname as firstname0_0_, user0_.lastname as lastname0_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?
Hibernate: select user_role0_.id as id2_0_, user_role0_.name as name2_0_ from user_roles user_role0_ where user_role0_.id=?
Hibernate: select user_statu0_.id as id1_0_, user_statu0_.name as name1_0_ from user_status user_statu0_ where user_statu0_.id=?
Hibernate: select interactio0_.id as id12_0_, interactio0_.name as name12_0_ from interaction_status interactio0_ where interactio0_.id=?
Hibernate: select interactio0_.id as id10_0_, interactio0_.name as name10_0_, interactio0_.parent as parent10_0_ from interaction_categ1 interactio0_ where interactio0_.id=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select interactio0_.id as id8_0_, interactio0_.name as name8_0_ from interaction_type interactio0_ where interactio0_.id=?
Hibernate: select categs1x0_.parent as parent1_, categs1x0_.id as id1_, categs1x0_.id as id10_0_, categs1x0_.name as name10_0_, categs1x0_.parent as parent10_0_ from interaction_categ1 categs1x0_ where categs1x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select categs2x0_.parent as parent1_, categs2x0_.id as id1_, categs2x0_.id as id11_0_, categs2x0_.name as name11_0_, categs2x0_.parent as parent11_0_ from interaction_categ2 categs2x0_ where categs2x0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id0_0_, user0_.username as username0_0_, user0_.role as role0_0_, user0_.status as status0_0_, user0_.password as password0_0_, user0_.firstname as firstname0_0_, user0_.lastname as lastname0_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?
Hibernate: select interactio0_.id as id12_0_, interactio0_.name as name12_0_ from interaction_status interactio0_ where interactio0_.id=?
Hibernate: select interactio0_.id as id12_0_, interactio0_.name as name12_0_ from interaction_status interactio0_ where interactio0_.id=?
Hibernate: select interactio0_.id as id9_0_, interactio0_.name as name9_0_ from interaction_channel_type interactio0_ where interactio0_.id=?
Hibernate: select interactio0_.id as id12_0_, interactio0_.name as name12_0_ from interaction_status interactio0_ where interactio0_.id=?
Hibernate: select interactio0_.id as id9_0_, interactio0_.name as name9_0_ from interaction_channel_type interactio0_ where interactio0_.id=?
Hibernate: select interactio0_.id as id9_0_, interactio0_.name as name9_0_ from interaction_channel_type interactio0_ where interactio0_.id=?
Hibernate: select customer_l0_.id as id5_0_, customer_l0_.name as name5_0_ from customer_language customer_l0_ where customer_l0_.id=?
Hibernate: select products0_.account_holder as account5_1_, products0_.id as id1_, products0_.id as id13_0_, products0_.product_name as product2_13_0_, products0_.status as status13_0_, products0_.account_holder as account5_13_0_, products0_.account_num as account3_13_0_, products0_.account_limit as account4_13_0_ from product products0_ where products0_.account_holder=?
Hibernate: select product_st0_.id as id14_0_, product_st0_.name as name14_0_ from product_status product_st0_ where product_st0_.id=?
Hibernate: select customer_s0_.id as id4_0_, customer_s0_.name as name4_0_ from customer_salutation customer_s0_ where customer_s0_.id=?
Hibernate: select customer_s0_.id as id6_0_, customer_s0_.name as name6_0_ from customer_status customer_s0_ where customer_s0_.id=?
Committing the database transaction
Hibernate: update product set product_name=?, status=?, account_holder=?, account_num=?, account_limit=? where id=?
```

Comment: `many unnecessary queries`  what are those queries ?

Comment: All the SELECT statements retrieving the properties of the customer object. I do not understand why it has to retrieve these properties while I am not using them. All I want to achieve is to set the customer object as the owner of my product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out why this was happening. As the fetch type of the field is LAZY, the object is not supposed to be fetched unless it is actually used (e.g. a property of it is called).
For this case it is not setting the customer for product that is causing all the unnecessary queries to run. The actual reason is the object being included in the response. Since I initially did not specify what object I want to send back to the caller in my action mapping, by default all the properties of the action class (including productbean), is sent back to the caller. In fact what solved my problem was these few simple lines:

```
<action name="updateProduct" class="net.scicom.seylan.view.ProductAction" method="saveOrUpdate">
        <result type="json">
            <param name="root">
                product
            </param>
        </result>
 </action>
```

NOTE: `product` object is different from `productbean`. `Product` is an object of class `ProductViewModel` which is the class our results coming from database is transformed to.

Initially my updateProduct mapping looked something like this which was where the issue was coming from:

```
<action name="updateProduct" class="net.scicom.seylan.view.ProductAction" method="saveOrUpdate">
    </action>
```

---

Lesson learnt: Always specify the object you want to send back to the caller in a JSON call

Answer (score 1):

Use `session.load(Customer.class, customerId)`, instead of `session.get()`. It will create a lazy proxy, assuming the customer exists, instead of actually getting the customer from the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am already using Load in my getCustomer method but still see all the queries running.

Comment: Then, if we can't see the code and the queries, I don't know how we can help more.

Comment: Hi JB. Really appreciate your help. I just edited the question and included all related codes and queries.

Comment: Try removing the call to saveOrUpdate(). It's useless, since your entities are attached.

Comment: I tried that too but the queries are still running. I noticed it only happens when I set the customer for my productbean. So, it is not CustomerManager.getCustomer(this.productCustomer) that is causing the unnecessary queries to run since they only run when  executing productbean.setCustomer(...) statement. Even when I try to sysout a property of the retrieved customer object, it only runs one query to select that property. so I am guessing whatever it is, it has something to do with my setCustomer() method.